# Function not locally injective at $0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let $f : (-1, 1) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be given by $f(0) = 0$ and $f(t) = t + 2t^2 \sin(1/t)$ for $t \neq 0$. I've already proved that $f'(0) = 1$ and that $f'$ is bounded. I'm having trouble showing that $f$ is not locally injective at 0.

My idea was to try to find points $x_n \rightarrow 0$  where $f'(x_n) = 0$ but $f''(x_n) \neq 0$, since these points would be local extrema and thus (I think) $f$ could not be injective near them. We have (away from $0$) $f'(t) = 1 + 4t \sin(1/t) - 2 \cos(1/t)$. If we let $a_n =\frac{1}{\frac{\pi}{2} + 2 n \pi}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{2(n+1)\pi}$ then we have $b_n < a_n$, $f'(b_n) = -1$ and $f'(a_n) = 1 + 4 a_n > 0$, so between $b_n$ and $a_n$ we find $x_n$ such that $f'(x_n) = 0$. I'm having trouble reasoning about $f''(x_n)$ though. What can I do in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that there exists $a>0$ such that your function $f$ is injective on $I=(-a,a)$. As 
$f$ is continuous, $f$ is strictly monotonic on $I$. Then $f^{\prime}$ has a constant sign on $I$. Then use your $a_n$ and $b_n$.